# α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds and alkyl addition

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In my book it is suggested that in order to add alkyl groups in α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds we use organometallic reagents such as organolithium reagents. 
In the previous chapters it was suggested that the addition of alkyl groups in carbonyl compounds with saturated chains it is conducted by using secondary amines that produce enamines.

I would like to know if it is possible to add alkyl groups in α,β-unsaturated carbonyl compounds by using secondary amines.

[image]

Comment: Where is the alkyl group being added to the unsaturated carbonyl? In a 1,2- or a 1,4-sense?         Could you possibly [edit] your post to include the example from the book (you can upload photographs to imgur using the toolbar when editing)

Comment: The addition is 1,2 with organolithium reagents and 1,4 with organocopper reagents. The book is the 6th edition of ''Organic Chemistry" by Vollhardt and Schore. I'm sorry but I am not able to upload a photo.

Comment: Do you have a page reference? I have a copy of the book and can upload a picture of the relevant scheme for you

Comment: In chapter 18-4 (p. 934 of the Greek edition) the use of secondary amines is presented, while the use of organometallic compounds is presented in chapter 18-10 (p. 950). 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Enamines do not add alkyl groups to carbonyl compounds. They are enolate synthons ($d^2$). Are you confusing this with the Baylis-Hilman reaction?

Comment: Which position are you trying to alkylate at?

Comment: @KG3 I'm not saying that enamines add alkyl groups. What it is suggested is that by forming an enamine, one has a better reactant to then add an alkyl chain, instead of using a base straightforward since that would end up as an aldol reaction.

Comment: @orthocresol Either 1,2- or 1,4-. However, I think only 1,2- would be plausible.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly (I do not have the book), it goes like this:
[image]
(Ref. J. Am. Chem. Soc.  85, 2, 207-222)

In short I would say that it is not possible to perform the reaction in question in the same way with the Stork enamine alkylation simply because—due to the α,β unsaturation of the ketone—the enamine can not be produced with pyrrolidine. Also, I performed a Reaxys search and found no relevant results. (Of course, I might have missed something.) However, I did find a couple of interesting reactions between cyclohexenone and pyrrolidine which I submit below for completion:

[image]

And the following L-Proline organocatalytic reaction taken from: Tetrahedron Letters, 2010, vol. 51, #38, p. 5086 - 5090. Note that compounds 1 and 2 in the scheme were isolated.

[image]

However it must be noted that generally, using a different α, β unsaturated ketone and a different amine to the ones used above, the reaction in question is possible as demonstrated by user55119 in his answer here: [Why enamine formation does not occur with α,β unsaturated ketones?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99987/why-enamine-formation-does-not-occur-with-%CE%B1-%CE%B2-unsaturated-ketones?noredirect=1#comment186687_99990)

Comment: The pyrrolidine enamine of cyclohexanone reaction with methyl vinyl ketone does not stop at the Michael addition product but undergoes an aldol condensation (overall Robinson annulation) to form the pyrrolidine enamine of the enone. This species hydrolyzes with buffered aqueous acetic acid and not with water or aqueous mineral acid. [G. Stork, et al.; pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00885a021]

Comment: @user55119 Well spotted, i have edited it accordingly but did not include all the details so it wont get unnecessary complicated for what the question is asking. Added your reference however so people can take a closer look if needed. Ta!

Comment: @AMM Thank you for your response. However, is there no way the last step of the enamine formation mechanism, the deprotonation, occurs at the CH3- side or would such a structure be impossible to exist?

Comment: @ΑντώνιοςΚελεσίδης I was thinking the same thing . The only reports of such compounds i found were: Chem. Commun. (London), 1967,0, 862-863 , and Journal of the Chemical Society, Perkin Transactions 1:  Organic and Bio-Organic Chemistry (1972-1999) (1977), (23), 2571-80;  really old articles which i am not sure i trust (for the search i kept the 2,3 and 5,6 unsaturated ring with NA2 on the 1 carbon with A stands for Any atom). Regardless, it is not common and if it does exist it looks like not accessible via the route above. This makes a good question by itself if u like to post, or shall i?

Comment: I see. You mean to post a different question regarding the existence of a "diene/amine" structure? If you'd like to, sure. :)

Comment: @ΑντώνιοςΚελεσίδης I was thinking something like: why the reaction you suggest is not observed and why the putative product is not commonly found in the literature. Maybe the computational people will jump in (kai ego Antonis parepiptontos).

Comment: People might redirect it back to this original question but I don't see why not try it. Go ahead and I'll keep an eye συνονάματε.

Comment: @ Αντώνιος Κελεσίδης: Could you be more explicit as to what you mean by the "CH3- side in your response to AMM. Perhaps I can help.

Comment: @user55119 I have posted the new question here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99987/why-enamine-formation-does-not-occur-for-α-β-unsaturated-ketones,  an organic chemist would be helpful here i suppose so let us know!

Comment: @AMM: The buffered hydrolysis conditions are for dienamines, not enamines. See, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99987/why-enamine-formation-does-not-occur-with-%ce%b1-%ce%b2-unsaturated-ketones

Comment: Hi, may I ask, which software you used to plot these nice organic chemistry structures? Thanks!

Comment: @YangxinZhang It is called chemdraw.

Answer (score 4):

I think that adding alkyl groups to $\alpha$ - $\beta$ unsaturated carbonyl compounds are possible through Enamine synthesis by Secondary amines. But the alkylation will be at the $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ positions as follows. 
 For simplicity, if we take the corresponding carbonyl compound as Cyclohex-$2$-en-$1$-one, the plausible pathways for alkylation are as follows,
[image]

Now, the first step of forming an enamine is already reported. The link for the JACS paper is https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja061104y .
In this paper, preparation of enamine (by using **S-Proline** as a secondary amine)  of similar kind of $\alpha$ - $\beta$ unsaturated compound has been reported. One of the major reaction in this paper is the following, 
[image]

Thus it is confirmed that such kind of doubly conjugated enamine formation is possible. The remaining two steps for $\alpha$ - alkylation is also reported earlier. For details, see the paper 
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/recl.19881070906 

 Here they have done the following reaction related to this context,
[image]

Here $\gamma$ alkylation was disfavoured to preserve the aromaticity of the benzene ring. 
But in general, $\gamma$ alkylation forms again a conjugated carbonyl compound, and hence forms the thermodynamically more stable product. So,$\gamma$ -alkylation is more favoured at higher temperature, whereas the $\alpha$ -alkylated product is a kinetic product. 
 **Thus, it is also possible to do alkylation of $\alpha$ - $\beta$ unsaturated compound using a secondary amine, but those alkylation will be specifically in $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ positions (not on $\beta$ positions)**.